# Why did Separatist Council believe Sidious till the end?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, revenge-of-the-sith

Sidious made a lot of promises, first to Trade Federation and Nute Gunray (["I will make it legal"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz20lu2AM2k), ["Not for a Sith"](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/e58a7cf7-f6c1-41f0-9887-fd64c69197a3)), latter to CIS as a whole. Yet, all of his promises for quick victory turn out to be hollow and unfulfilled.

Finally, we have Separatist Council hiding on Utapau, with their final desperate offensive on Coruscant defeated and Dooku dead. Then they move to Mustafar, and shortly after that Grievous is killed. Yet they still believe Sidious and wait patiently there like sheep to be slaughtered.

Members of the Council supposed to be shrewd and cunning beings, that made it to the top using treachery of their own. Yet, none of them suspect Sidious (although they certainly have some knowledge about the Sith), and none of them tries to strike out on their own. There were not attempts to flee, surrender or negotiate with Republic, bribe their way out etc ... either individually or in group. How could that be explained ?

Comment: Bad/lazy writing?

Comment: Fear of Sidious, aware of Order 66. There's at least two reasons to stick around on the winning side. (Sure the second of which isn't great, but it's possible)

Comment: They were not intelligent enough to make their own decisions, happy being pulled by the strings by Sidious

Comment: @Edlothiad Care to write answer ?

Comment: With my speculation, no I likely won’t, I think Tim’s answer is quite good

Answer (score 10):

## Because they were cowards

According to the prequel movies official novelizations, Separatist leader [Nute Gunray](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gunray) (Viceroy of the Trade Federation) is a cowardly, greedy and not very intelligent being. His fear is often betrayed by foul smell.

<sup>From Episode 3 official novelization, part 2, chapter 10</sup>

> *[Grievous]:*  Repulsive sniveling grub-greedy scum, both of them. And the rest of the Separatist leadership was every bit as vile.

It is worth pointing that Gunray was disgusted even by his ally, Grievous, for cowardice and repulsive appearance.

In the movies, he is also shown very afraid of Darth Sidious. And it is not likely that such a creature could detect that he is being simply used as a disposable puppet.

Gunray (and also other Spearatist leaders) does not know the Sith lord's other identity, that he manipulates both sides. Although there is an imminent danger of losing the war, and facing charges from the winning side, he is more afraid of the Sith's wrath than anything else. At least, the Republic would be fair to their enemy, but the Sith would never be.

For other Separatist leaders, I think the logic could be the same.

Comment: A quote would be useful, but I'd thought as much that a canon answer would exist.

Comment: Ah apologies. Too quick.

Comment: I don't see how you get to be Viceroy of a trade group without some degree of cunning, unless nepotism was involved.

Comment: also it was known that their species (gunrays) was cowardly....the jedi even mentioned it in phantom menace while waiting for the viceroy to appear.

Comment: @Thomas  They are Neimodians

Comment: @JAB Gunray was cunning, but not very smart. Compared to the Sith Lord, he was no cunning at all.

Comment: @TimSparrow Gunray was perhaps cowardly, but he was not stupid. And what about others ? As you said it, they didn't know much about Sidious and had little reason to trust him .

Comment: @rs.29 I still think he was not a very smart being. In Ep.2, his personal vendetta against Padme led the Jedi to investigation, which led to early discovery of the Separatist droid army. 
As for the others, I have every reason to trust the quoted Grievous's judgement of them. They were too afraid of Sidious to do anything against his will.

Comment: @TimSparrow I don't think it was early, more like perfect timing for Sidious real plan (Clone War, not Separatist victory) . Also, fear factor - they did not met Sidious in person. They were perhaps afraid of his henchman (Dooku and Grievous) . But they were both dead now. For all they knew, Sidious could have been just a holo illusion.

Comment: @rs.29 we do not know if they ever saw Sidious in person (we see only holo in the movies. But the way Gunray's voice trembles each time he tells bad news to Sidious suggests that he is very much afraid of that person. So afraid that he can do something stupid. As for the timing, we do not exactly know if it was perfect. Maybe the original idea was to wipe as many Jedi as possible in the initial battle on Geonosis, so that Order 66 won't be necessary. Sidious seems to always have a Plan B.

Comment: @TimSparrow Original plan - I don't think so, Dooku and sidious never intended that filthy aliens from CIS win the war. Instead, they wanted to turn public opinion on Jedi, and then eliminate them. That is the reason for creation of Clone army. As for fear - what was the reason for it ? Did Sidious ever display Dark side powers over holonet ? Or they were afraid just because he had powerful servants (now dead) ? Don't concentrate just on Gunray.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74975/discussion-between-timsparrow-and-rs-29).

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of [choice-supportive bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice-supportive_bias).  Put most simply, having made a bad decision, the Council chooses to interpret ongoing evidence in ways that confirm they made the right choice, and ignore that they made the wrong choice.

To quote Wikipedia (emphasis mine),

> In cognitive science, one predictable way that memories of choice
>   options are distorted is that positive aspects tend to be remembered
>   as part of the chosen option, whether or not they originally were part
>   of that option, and negative aspects tend to be remembered as part of
>   rejected options. *Once an action has been taken, the ways in which
>   we evaluate the effectiveness of what we did may be biased.*

To be fair, trying to switch sides once it reached mid-game would have likely meant that they were torn apart by both sides... so staying with that bad decision may have been the best of what were only poor options.  (But as portrayed on screen, blinded by their own bad choices seems more in line with their characters.)

Comment: Is there anything on screen, in script, or in novelisations that suggests they were victims of "choice-supportive bias"?

Comment: Put another way, "in for a penny, in for a pound"

Comment: @Edlothiad, no.  It's an opinion based on their actions, and as with any psychological judgement by a non-professional, could be total hogwash.  (If you want semi-aqueous hogwash, see a professional.)  That said, it does seem very in line with what I recall of the film.